# Job - Messages - After an event is completed, uncheck check boxes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

In the messages section of jobs there are two buttons in your inbox, **Mark as unread** and **Mark as read**. The point here is to select a message by clicking a check box and then clicking the button to fire the event to either mark the message read or unread.

After this is complete, the check boxes are left checked. This doesn't make sense as after you perform the event you have to go back and uncheck the ones you had done to check off other ones.

Example:

I wanted to mark two messages unread and one message read. I clicked two of the items and clicked the button *Mark as unread*. As soon as that event completed both messages were marked unread, but the checks in the check boxes were left checked - they should be unchecked.

I then had to uncheck these two messages and check off the one that I wanted to mark read. I propose this should be changed such that the checkboxes are unchecked automatically after the event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

We're mirroring the behaviour of Gmail and Outlook here so I don't think it should change in order to remain consistent with those familiar interfaces.